# GoogleTest: EXPECT_THROW error: statement has no effect

Tags: c++, googletest

I am trying to use EXPECT_THROW in my testing, but I am running into a error I have been unable to resolve

So this is what I am trying to do

```
uint64_t u64 = bstt->inner_Bits_get_uint64();
EXPECT_THROW(u64 != 0, BadArg) << "Get uint32 returned 0!";
EXPECT_TRUE(u64 == ((1L << test_flags3_1) | (1L << test_flags3_2))) << "uint64 didnt match u64=" << u64 << "expected " << ((1L << test_flags3_1) | (1L << test_flags3_2));

uint32_t u32 = bstt->inner_Bits_get_uint32();
EXPECT_THROW(u32 != 0, BadArg) << "Get uint32 returned 0!";
EXPECT_TRUE(u32 == ((1 << test_flags3_1) | (1 << test_flags3_2))) << "uint32 didnt match u32=" << u32 << "expected " << ((1 << test_flags3_1) | (1 << test_flags3_2));
```

The actual results are stored in the u64 and u32 variables and BarArg is the exception type.

The error I get is

```
error: statement has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
  EXPECT_THROW(u64 != 0, BadArg) << "Get uint32 returned 0!";
               ~~~~^~~~
```

Comment: You have enabled `-Werror`. If you didn't this would only be a warning, but it is correct. The line `u64 != 0` has absolutely no effect whatsoever and the value is not used. In particular comparison between fundamental types cannot throw. So what why are you using `EXPECT_THROW`? Do you want `EXPECT_NE(u64, 0)` instead?

Comment: Did you oversimplyfy your example? Your log messages seem to assume that GoogleTest will throw something in `EXPECT_THROW` when it's first argument is `false`. That's not correct. If you want a fatal error (one which stops further execution of test), use `ASSERT_*` macro family (e.g. `ASSERT_NE`). If you really expect `uint64_t != int` to throw something, we need an [mcve] to answer precisely - why would it throw? what should happen when it throws? What is BadArg?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is tha tif u64!=0 then throw BadArg and don't terminate the program

Comment: Where and for what purpose do you want to catch the exception? What is `BadArg`?

Comment: But why do you want to throw anything? It doesn't make much sense if you catch exception immidiately after throwing (and there is no code that would be omitted because of exception). `EXPECT_NE` will confirm that the value is different than 0 (and your next `EXPECT_EQ` will likely also confirm that). Sure, it is possible to do (`EXPECT_THROW(if(u64 != 0) throw BadArg;, BadArg)` should do the trick) , but I don't see any reason why would you want that overcomplicated solution.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I understand that OP wants the test macro to throw an exception of type `BadArg` if the condition `u64 != 0` is not satisfied (rather than continue the tests or return from the function as `ASSERT_*` does.). But I am not sure what they want to do with this exception after it is caught and where.

Comment: @shafi97 Maybe you just want to put each pair of tests in a new function? `ASSERT_*` will only exit the current function on failure, not the entire program.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I had a wrong concept of EXCEPT_THROW what you said makes sense